# "Where does he come into all of this?"

Tags: usage

I came across the following on [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/tagged/pisoi?sort=top):

> **A:** The more I get to know you through your answers, the more I like
> you. Because I see how you are harmonious, smart, down to earth and
> with a fabalous sense of humor. And you are very patient in answering
> our dumb questions. I love you , Henry loves you, all of us love
> you!!!!
>
> **B:** Thank you Nonny, this warms my heart. I had a long and exhausting day
> and I came home to your lovely message. What a treat.
> Also your questions are not dumb.
> H-hold up - Henry?! **Where does he come into
> all of this?**
> I just hope that whenever he goes down the rabbit hole of
> his morbid curiosity, as he calls it, that he only sees lovely things
> written about him.

What connotation does the the question in bold have here? Is it sarcastic or is it genuinely used to seek information?
Could you also tell me whether it sounds formal?

Comment: Why would you think it was sarcastic?  Remember, we don't know anything of the back story of Henry, Nonny, or anything else.  Please link to the Tumblr post, so we can all see some more context.  _  Also, It's tumblr,  of course it's not formal.

Comment: @James K I misunderstood the question and thought it might be sarcastic. I found the page by chance and I don't use Tumblr so I wasn't sure about the degree of formalilty its content has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not sarcastic. It is neutral in tone.

I would say it is just slightly informal.

It means “What does Henry have to do with this?” or “Why have you mentioned Henry in this conversation?”

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I just come across this phrase. Accoring to the translation, it means

> What does all of this have to do with him?

[come into something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come-into)